# How to add multiple tables in xml document

Tags: xml, coldfusion

```
<cfset BUSOBJ=XmlNew()>
<cfset BUSOBJ.xmlRoot = XmlElemNew(BUSOBJ,"EMPLOYEEDATA")>
<cfset BUSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[1].NOTICE = XmlElemNew(BUSOBJ,"NOTICE")>
<cfset BUSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[1].NOTICE.XmlText = "SomeMsg">
<cfset BUSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[1].NOTICE = XmlElemNew(BUSOBJ,"STARTDATE")>
<cfset BUSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[1].NOTICE.XmlText = "#startdate#">
<cfset BUSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[1].NOTICE = XmlElemNew(BUSOBJ,"ENDDATE")>
<cfset BUSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[1].NOTICE.XmlText = "#enddate#">

<cfset empIndex = 1>
<cfloop query="qEmpData">
    <cfset empIndex ++>
    <cfset BUSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[empIndex] = XmlElemNew(BUSINESSOBJ,"EMPLOYEE")>
    <cfset BUSINESSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[empIndex].EMPLOYEE_ID = XmlElemNew(BUSINESSOBJ,"EMPLOYEE_ID")>
    <cfset BUSINESSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[empIndex].EMPLOYEE_ID.XmlText = "#qEmpData.EMPLOYEE_ID#">
    <cfset BUSINESSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[empIndex].EMPLOYEE_TYPE = XmlElemNew(BUSINESSOBJ,"EMPLOYEE_TYPE")>
    <cfset BUSINESSOBJ.EMPLOYEEDATA.XmlChildren[empIndex].EMPLOYEE_TYPE.XmlText = "#qEmpData.EMPLOYEE_TYPE#">
    .....blah,blah,blah
```

Now, I have another table that I want to include (loop through) in this XML document and I cannot figure out how. I thought I would be able to do something like setting 'BUSOBJ.EMPLTYPELOOKUP...', but could not get that to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

emplTypes (lookup table - id used in above table queried from qEmpData)
id
name